# Chrome extension content security policy and permissions

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, twilio, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to do a Chrome extension and i have problems with the content security policy.

I create a popup.html with a json call in the popup.js called in the header. i also add another .js file on a remote server, i can't include it since it's a api car to a external service.

I tryed everything with the manifest.json.

```
"permissions": [ //"optional_permissions": [
        "http://*.myjsonserver.com/",
        "http://*.twilio.com/*",
        "https://*.twilio.com/*"
        //"http://*/*",
        //"https://*/*"
    ],
```

i tryed this.

```
"manifest_version": 2,
    "content_security_policy": "connect-src 'self' http://myjsonserver.com; object-src 'self'", //connect-src
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://static.twilio.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Or should i add the javascript this way?

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://static.twilio.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

I get this error on google chrome inspector.

```
Refused to load the script 'http://myjsonserver.com/get_token_cb.php?callback=jQuery210007401883858256042_144745747' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://static.twilio.com".
---------------
chrome-extension://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/refs/6359b40/twilio.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED    chrome-extension://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/refs/6359b40/twilio.min.js
```

but nothing work, myjsonserver.com it not on a https server and it's on my own server. the twilio.com url is to access the twilio api from javascript.

This is just for testing because later it will be on the background.js

I tryed it all but i'm lost and i have no clue.

Comment: Remove csp, you need `"http://*.myjsonserver.com/"` permission only. Do not load remote scripts, use json and local scripts to parse it. Don't do XHR from content scripts (not sure where you include `twilio.min.js`): background and popup only should work just fine.

Comment: i should load remote js, from twilio i have no other choice. I saw in the Twilio code they are calling another js file.

Comment: I also just find that i can't make jQuery ajax request on a remote server but i can do a pure javascript `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`
What is the difference, why i can't do a ajax call with jQuery but i can with XMLHttpRequest ?

Answer (score 2):

Lots going on here - I can say that Google recommends that you DO serve JS from the extension rather than from the internet if possible (so if you need jQuery, you would bundle it with your extension). Regarding the specific error you reported, only the second `content_security_policy` is taking effect. You can see in [their documents](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) that they only specify one of these attributes in the manifest.

To solve the error you are facing, I believe you want:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://myjsonserver.com https://static.twilio.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: [`http:` schemes cannot be whitelisted.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) Use `https:` instead to whitelist remote scripts (or preferably, bundle it with the extension).